# Change the connection string of the auto generated WEB API authentication?

Tags: sql-server, database, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I created a WEB API project that involves individual user accounts authentication. I have already an existing database with additional tables, how can I link my database to this project instead of creating a new one?

I  tried to add an ADO entity model but still it can't reach my database.

What should be done in this case?

This is the web.config file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please 
visit
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301879
-->
<configuration>
 <configSections>
 <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit 
 http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
 <section name="entityFramework" 
 type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, 
 EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source= 
  (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet- 
  FlutterBackend-20200123055259.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-FlutterBackend- 
  20200123055259;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings></appSettings>
  <system.web>
<authentication mode="None" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
 <modules>
  <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
 </modules>

  <handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers></system.webServer>
  <runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" 
    publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" 
    publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" 
    publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" 
     />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" 
     />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" 
    publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
 </runtime>
 <entityFramework>
 <defaultConnectionFactory 
   type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
   <providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
 </entityFramework>
 <system.codedom>
  <compilers>
  <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" 

   type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
  <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
   </compilers>
 </system.codedom>
 </configuration>
```

I want to apply the authentication actions on my own database instead of the one autogenerated by the asp.net

Comment: First thing is to include some code snippets so we can understand your code/question.

Comment: Done, i want to change the default connection string to my own database instead of the one autogenerated, i tried to edit the connection string but didn't work. @DaleK